# Lazy loading not working in spring data jpa one to many bi directional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

spring data jpa project where i have two entities with one to many bi directional mapping i am trying to fecth objects lazily but in response is like eager fetch.

response:

[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "kyoot",
            "postComments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "review": "acsad",
                    "post": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "review": "cadfs",
                    "post": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "afhv",
            "postComments": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "review": "vdv",
                    "post": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "review": "acs",
                    "post": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

```
The classes:



     @Entity
        @Table(name = "post_comment")
        @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id",scope = PostComment.class) 
            public class PostComment implements Serializable{

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Id
                @Column(name = "id")
                @GeneratedValue
                private Long id;

                @Column(name = "review")
                private String review;

                @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @JoinColumn(name = "post_id",nullable = false)
                private Post post;

                public Long getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                public void setId(Long id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                public String getReview() {
                    return review;
                }

                public void setReview(String review) {
                    this.review = review;
                }


                public Post getPost() {
                    return post;
                }

                public void setPost(Post post) {
                    this.post = post;
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    final int prime = 31;
                    int result = 1;
                    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    if (this == obj)
                        return true;
                    if (obj == null)
                        return false;
                    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                        return false;
                    PostComment other = (PostComment) obj;
                    if (id == null) {
                        if (other.id != null)
                            return false;
                    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }



            }
        package com.srinivas.assetz.domain;

        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.List;

        import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "post")
        @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id",scope = Post.class) 
        public class Post implements Serializable{

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "id")
            private int id;

            @Column(name = "title")
            private String title;

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            private List<PostComment> postComments;


            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getTitle() {
                return title;
            }

            public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.title = title;
            }


            public List<PostComment> getPostComments() {
                return postComments;
            }

            public void setPostComments(List<PostComment> postComments) {
                this.postComments = postComments;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + id;
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                    return true;
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
                Post other = (Post) obj;
                if (id != other.id)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }





        }

    @Repository
    public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Integer> {

    }
    public interface PostService {
        public Iterable<Post> getAllPosts();    
    }
@Service

public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Iterable<Post> getAllPosts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return postRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please send you DAO class or your Service class that executes query.

Comment: @Moodi i have added service that you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You only have lazy on the entity PostComment in this part:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "post_id",nullable = false)
 private Post post;
```

But your entity Post is like that (you do not have lazy there):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PostComment> postComments;
```

And that is the reason why when you are retrieving Post you are getting the PostComment as well. So to avoid that include lazy on entity Post, something like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
orphanRemoval = true)
private List<PostComment> postComments;
```

Comment: `FetchType.LAZY` is the default one fetch value in `@OneToMany` relation. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html

Comment: Yes you are right, but I have a project with spring and I have to specify Lazy otherwise the system act like Eager

Comment: @SergVasylchak I have added fetch on post side still result is same